# How handle errors in php script fired by Jquery.ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, error-handling

I have php-script, firing with jquery ajax function. Somthing like this:

```
$("a.test").click (function () {
var new_id = $(this).attr("new_id");


$.ajax({
    url: 'test.php',  
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        async: true,
    data: ({
        new_id : new_id
        }),
    success: function (data) { 
        alert (data);       
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('error');
    }
});
return false;
});
```

Now, a have some errors in test.php, but I can't see them. Sript just runs and I have no feedback, only error alert (alert ('error')).

How can I get back errors, that I have in test.php to handle them?

Comment: Simplest solution is to open the console and go to Network tab and see the respond of the request. This solution is if you don't want to change code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `echo` the errors in test.php, you can simply do:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.php',  
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        async: true,
    data: ({
        new_id : new_id
        }),
    success: function (data) { 
        alert (data);       
    },
    error: function(data){
        alert('error:'+data);
    }
});
return false;
});
```

**Edit:**

I usually do something like this. In test.php if you get an error, create an array with your error info and echo it json encoded:

```
$message=array('error' => 1,'message' => '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">' . $login['message'] . '</div>' );
echo json_encode($message);
```

Now in your jquery you can retrive the error by:

```
success: function (data) { 
        alert (data);       
    },
    error: function(data){
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        alert(obj.message);
    }
```

When you have it in array like this you dont even need `error: function(data)` anymore, since you can simply:

```
success: function (data) { 
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);      
    if (obj.error) {
        // do something
        alert (obj.message); 
    }else{
        // do something else
    }
 },
```

Answer (score 2):

On test.php you could show errors using the code explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/6525724

And then on this page instead of alert('error') you could use alert(data).

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
    alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
}
```